# GCM POST from application

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to use Google Cloud Messaging to notify users when there is new data to receive from the server. Sending Messages using GCM is defined as:

`To send a message, the application server issues a POST request to https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send.`

Is it possible to send this HTTP POST request from the android application? I've tried to implement this using the method's I've been using successfully to POST to my server hosted by MongoLab. My attempt is as follows:

```
    input_json.put("registration_ids", RegistrationIDs);
    input_json.put("data", data);
    param = new StringEntity(input_json.toString());

    HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
    int some_reasonable_timeout = (int) (20 * DateUtils.SECOND_IN_MILLIS);
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, some_reasonable_timeout);
    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, some_reasonable_timeout);

    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);
    HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);
    request.setEntity(param);
    request.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    request.setHeader("Authorization", API_KEY);
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);

    StatusLine status = response.getStatusLine();
    if (status.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK){
        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
        result = responseHandler.handleResponse(response);
    }
```

I do not receive any HTTP errors or a response from the gcm server so I don't really know where to go from here. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score -1):

Is it possible to send this HTTP POST request from the android application?

This is how I post all related device information on user registration in the GCMintent class. Hope this helps answer your question, I am not 100% what you are trying to do tbh.

```
@Override
protected void onRegistered(Context ctx, String regId) {
    // send regId to your server
    sendRegistrationIdToServer(regId, "01");    
}


public void sendRegistrationIdToServer(String registrationId, String func) {
    //Send the reg info to server
    Log.d(TAG, "Sending registration ID to my application server");
    String deviceId = Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Secure.ANDROID_ID);
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(URL);
    Context context = getApplicationContext();

    try {
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("deviceid", deviceId));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("func", func));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("registrationid",registrationId));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("app", GetPackageName()));

        post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

        String line = "";
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            Log.e("HttpResponse", line);
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("HttpResponse", "broke");
    }
}
```

It can be easily adapted to send Json.